# Generating urban blocks by road centerlines using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, road

I work on cartographic generalization project and I need to generate urban blocks by road centerlines.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

General strategy for the solution:

1. Compute dissolved buffer area by road width. (Tool: *Buffer*)
2. Create bounding box of road layer. (Tool: *Extract layer extent*)
3. Remove the portion that overlaps the dissolved buffer. (Tool: *Difference*)
4. Convert multipolygon into single polygons since the result of 3 is a multipolygon. (Tool: *Multipart to singleparts*)

[image]

PyQGIS script:

```py
import processing as P

road_layer = iface.activeLayer() # road centerline
road_width = 15 # 15 meter

# 1
buffer = P.run("native:buffer",
                {'INPUT':road_layer, 'DISTANCE':road_width, 'SEGMENTS':15,
                 'END_CAP_STYLE':0, 'JOIN_STYLE':0, 'MITER_LIMIT':2,
                 'DISSOLVE':True, 'OUTPUT':'memory:buffer'})["OUTPUT"]

# OR if the layer has WIDTH field for each road
# buffer = P.run("native:buffer",
#                 {'INPUT': road_layer, 'DISTANCE': QgsProperty.fromExpression('"WIDTH"'),
#                 'SEGMENTS':15, 'END_CAP_STYLE':0, 'JOIN_STYLE':0, 'MITER_LIMIT':2,
#                 'DISSOLVE':True, 'OUTPUT':'memory:buffer'})["OUTPUT"]

# 2
bbox = P.run("qgis:polygonfromlayerextent",
             {'INPUT':road_layer, 'ROUND_TO':0, 'OUTPUT':'memory:bbox'})["OUTPUT"]

# 3
diff = P.run("native:difference",
             {'INPUT':bbox, 'OVERLAY':buffer, 'OUTPUT':'memory:diff'})["OUTPUT"]

# 4
block_layer = P.run("native:multiparttosingleparts",
                  {'INPUT':diff, 'OUTPUT':'memory:block'})["OUTPUT"]

## remove fields (they are all about roads, not about blocks)
vpr = block_layer.dataProvider()
vpr.deleteAttributes(vpr.attributeIndexes())
##

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(block_layer)

# del buffer, bbox, diff
```